# Does SQL Server Validate a stored proc before running it?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have checked many threads now and I cant seem to find an answer for this, and I need to be fairly certain / confident that I am correct in assuming this before replying to a client.

so, as the heading states, *Does SQL Server validate a stored procedure before running it?*

IE: Even if i have an `IF statement` that will never meet a certain condition, will the code in that `IF statement condition` be checked and validated before running?

**EDIT:** Here is a quick example:

```
DECLARE @ParamSource VARCHAR(2) = 'V3'

IF @ParamSource = 'V1'
BEGIN
    --USE LINKED SERVER HERE WHICH THROWS AN ERROR ABOUT CONNECTIONS
END

IF @ParamSource = 'V3'
BEGIN
    --DO MY ACTUAL CODE
END
```

I will never meet that first condition, but for some reason, my stored proc is trying to validate on run time and keeps erroring.

Comment: They are validated (at least partially) when being initially built, but not at runtime.  This however isn't true for dynamic SQL which is never validated.  This is coming from personal experience, not from any documentation.  If you want to test this theory though, you can build out a simple stored procedure against a test table, then remove a column from the test table.  The stored procedure will still attempt to run, but will throw an error.

Comment: @user2366842- thanks for the reply... The reason I think its validating or doing something along those lines is because I am in the process of setting up a `Disaster Recovery environment` and one of the `IF statements` uses a linked server which I cant connect to for some reason (But, I never need to meet that condition, i can delete this code, but i just wanted to know if this is what SQL was doing?)

Comment: Deferred Name Resolution and Compilation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx (link updated)

Comment: This all depends on what you mean by "Validated".

Comment: With a linked server, you will normally get the syntax highlighting issues in SSMS, but it will run/"compile" just fine, provided the linked server is actually set up correctly.  As for the question of if you should delete it or not...if the linked server no longer exists, it might be best to simply comment out the offending code, as opposed to deleting it (especially seeing that SSMS doesn't have any way of reverting changes to stored procs short of a database restore).

Answer (score 2):

When a stored procedure is created, it is compiled, which means that each object used in a stored procedure is validated.  For all existing objects you also need to have access to them.  This will create an execution plan for this stored procedure, and as long as the procedure doesn't change, the execution plan should remain valid.  If any table object used in the stored procedure does not exist (table only, not linked servers), the execution plan will not be created at this point, but the procedure will be created if no other errors are found.

In your example, you need access to the linked server object to create your stored procedure.  After the creation, if you no longer have access to the linked server, your procedure will still run, but will generate an error if it needs to access the linked server `IF @ParamSource = 'V1'`.  However, if it doesn't hit the linked server `IF @ParamSource = 'V3'`, there will be no error.

Basically, it means that the user that creates the procedure needs to have access to the linked server.

Comment: More information about recompiling stored procedures: [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439(v=sql.105).aspx)